Why does my Razor page randomly display a 400 page?
I have a razor page that displays a login form if the user hasn't been authenticated and if the user has been authenticated it will display personal data. Sometimes when the user clicks on the button to login, instead of displaying the personal data, the page displays a 400 error message.

I'm not sure what is causing this.  It happens randomly.  I believe it is something to do with the anti-forgery token.  When I inspect the input, I can see that there is a hidden input field storing the request verification token.

This is what I currently have in the Personal.cshtml:
@page
@model PersonalModel
@{
    ViewData["PageTitle"] = String.Format("Profile: Statments for {0}", Model.CurrentUser.Name);
}

@if (!Model.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="row order-3">
        <div class="col">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Profile/Navigation.cshtml", Model.MenuItems)
            <h2 class="login-heading">Login to view your statement</h2>
            <span class="text-danger">All fields marked with * are required.</span>
            <form class="login-form-container" method="post">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken() // I don't believe this is needed as when I inspect without it I still see the hidden request verification token input.
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <label class="label-width" asp-for="ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="select-width disabled" asp-for="ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username" type="text" id="currentUsername" value="@Model.CurrentUser.ActiveDirectoryUserName" readonly>
                    <span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="label-width" asp-for="ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="select-width" asp-for="ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password" type="password" id="currentUserPassword" autocomplete="new-password" autofocus>
                    <span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix these problems:", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("currentUserPassword").addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.key === "Enter") {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
}
else
{
    <div class="row order-3">
        <div class="col">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/Profile/Navigation.cshtml", Model.MenuItems)
            <form class="form-container">
                <div class="selectRow">
                    <label class="label-width" for="dateDropdown">YYYYMM:</label>
                    <select id="dateDropdown" class="select-width" name="dataDropdown" asp-items="@Model.Dates" onchange="showPersonal()"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="selectRow">
                    <label class="label-width" for="officeDropdown">Office:</label>
                    <select id="officeDropdown" class="select-width" name="officeDropdown" asp-items="@Model.ProviderOffices" onchange="showPersonal()"></select>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" style="margin-bottom:15px">
                    <div class="grid-wrapper">
                        <table id="DataGrid" class="table-sm no-footer dataTable" style="width:100%"></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
// removed as not relevant
</script>
}

This is what I have in my model:
public class PersonalModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IDatabasePersonal _databaseUtility;
    private readonly IDatabaseUtility _dbUtility;
    public JArray MenuItems;
    public List<SelectListItem> Dates;
    public List<SelectListItem> ProviderOffices;
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public string Statement;
    [BindProperty]
    public ActiveDirectoryRequest ActiveDirectoryRequest { get; set; } = new ActiveDirectoryRequest();
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
  
    public PersonalModel(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IDatabasePersonal databaseUtility, IDatabaseUtility dbUtility) : base(configuration, httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _databaseUtility = databaseUtility;
        _dbUtility = dbUtility;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        MenuItems = JArray.Parse(_dbUtility.Submenu_Get(CurrentUser.Sid, CurrentUser.GroupsJson, Settings.SubmenuUrlList));

        if (IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SetStatement();
        }
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        MenuItems = JArray.Parse(_dbUtility.Submenu_Get(CurrentUser.Sid, CurrentUser.GroupsJson, Settings.SubmenuUrlList));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Username and password are required");
            return Page();
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username", "Username is required");
            return Page();
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password", "Password is required");
            return Page();
        }

        DirectoryEntry user = GetUser(ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "User not found");
            return Page();
        }

        IsAuthenticated = AuthenticateUser(user.Path, ActiveDirectoryRequest.Username, ActiveDirectoryRequest.Password);

        if (IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SetPersonal();
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "The password you entered is incorrect.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

// deleted methods I didn't find relevant to this problem
}

At one point I added the attribute [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] above the PersonalModel (I tried adding it just above the OnPost method but got a warning that it cannot be applied to handler methods.  It must be applied to the Razor page model or globally.  I tried running the application without the attribute and without the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() added in the form and get the same result, sometimes getting the 400 and sometimes displaying the Personal page.  When debugging, I set a breakpoint on the first line of the OnPost() and when I get the 400 page, it never hits the breakpoint.  I have also added the attribute  [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] above the PersonalModel and when I do that I haven't come across the 400 page.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong/how not to end up on the 400 page without adding the IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute?
Program.cs
public class Program
{

    public static string Environment = "Development";
    public static bool IsDevelopment = true;
    private static IHostBuilder WebHost = null;
    public static string WebRootPath;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Environment = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(Array.Find<string>(new string[]
        {
            "LIVE_ENVIRONMENT",
            "DOTNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
            "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT",
        }, delegate (string key) { return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Contains(key); }) ?? String.Empty) ?? Environment;

        WebHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment}.json", optional: false);

            if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var builtConfig = config.Build();
                var secretClient = new SecretClient(
                    new Uri(builtConfig["KeyVaultUrl"]),
                    new DefaultAzureCredential());
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(secretClient, new KeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
        WebHost.Build().Run();
    }

    public static IConfiguration Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<object, object> property in WebHost.Properties)
            {
                if (property.Value.GetType().Name.Equals("Startup", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return ((Startup)property.Value).Configuration;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string, Models.EndpointDefinition> EndpointDefinitions { get; set; } = new System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<string, Models.EndpointDefinition>();

When I make the request I see the token in the payload:


Hi @dev_in_training,  could you pls share your Program.cs also? If the project can always work when you use IgnoreAntiforgeryToken, it may caused by the invalid token. Also F12 to check the network when you click the button and send request if it contains the token. Razor Pages are automatically protected from XSRF/CSRF. You don't have to write any additional code.

@Rena when I view the network tab when sending the request it does contain the token.  I just edited my question to include the program.cs.

Hi @dev_in_training, how is you ActiveDirectoryRequest model? Does it only contains two properties named Username and Password?

@Rena, yes that is correct.                                                                                               public class ActiveDirectoryRequest     {         public string Username { get; set; }         public string Password { get; set; }     }
